# JavaScript: How to get a list of object keys of function argument object

Tags: javascript

I am using an object to pass in arguments, because the function has many parameters, and JavaScript doesnt support named arguments like Python.

I would like to check that all the args have a value passed in.
To do that I would like to loop over an array of the parameters, `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` in the example below.

I would like to keep the code dry and not hardcode the list.
I can access an object of the arguments with `arguments[0]`, but how does one access the parameters `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` programatically without hardcoding it?

```js
function run({foo, bar, baz}) {
    const requiredKeys = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']; // <- How to dynamically generate this
    for (const key in requiredKeys) {
        if (arguments[key] === null) throw `Please provide a value for ${key}`
    }
    console.log('done:', foo, bar, baz);
}
run({ foo: 1});
```

Comment: isn't typescript an option?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not everyone will see this as good practice, but you *could* use the source code of the function to extract the names of the properties of the parameter. [Mozilla Contributors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) note:

> Since ES2018, the spec requires the return value of toString() to be the exact same source code as it was declared, including any whitespace and/or comments

This makes parsing that string as reliable as the parsing system used.

For instance, you could use a decorator function that will extract the destructured parameter of the given function and return a function that will make the argument check:

```js
// Decorator
function requireArgsFor(f) {
    // Extract (once) the destructered parameter definition. 
    // This assumes it is present as first parameter, and is not nested:
    const params = /\(\s*\{([^}]*)/.exec(f)[1].split(",").map(param => param.trim());
    return { // Object wrapper to ensure the decorated function gets the same name
        [f.name](obj) {
            const missing = params.find(param => !Object.hasOwn(obj, param));
            if (missing) throw TypeError(`Argument ${missing} is missing in call of ${f.name}`);
            return f(obj);
        }
    }[f.name]; 
}

function run({foo, bar, baz}) {
    console.log('run is running');
}

// Decorate the above function
run = requireArgsFor(run);
console.log(`calling ${run.name} with all required arguments...`);
run({ foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 });
console.log(`calling ${run.name} with missing arguments...`);
run({ foo: 1 }); // Will trigger TypeError
```

You'd have to improve on the parsing part if you want to support more variations:

- For supporting default values, like `({ foo=1, bar, baz })`
- For allowing "unnamed" parameters to precede this final parameter, like `(a, b, {foo, bar, baz})`
- For supporting nested properties or arrays, like `({ foo: { bar }, baz: [first, ...rest] })`
- ...etc

Comment: Wow you found a way to get it done. Impressive. I was hoping it would as easy as using some built in keyword, similar to the `arguments` builtin. Like you said this works, but code maintainability would suffer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Don't destructure the argument (at least not initially) - instead, declare an array of the required keys into the code, then iterate over the array.

```js
function run(obj) {
    const requiredKeys = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
    for (const key of requiredKeys) {
        if (obj[key] === null || obj[key] === undefined) {
            throw new Error(`Please provide a value for ${key}`);
        }
    }
    console.log('done');
}
run({ foo: 1});
```

A nicer way would be to use JSDoc or TypeScript to indicate to the consumer of `run` that it must be called with a particular type of object - that way mistakes can be caught while writing code, rather than only when it's running.

Comment: Then how does one use the `requiredKeys` array to desctructure `obj` into indivisual variables without duplicating the list of variables? PS I agree about types, but waiting for native JS types before using types, I keep the build step simple, allows me debug easily.

Comment: Depends what you're doing with the values. If you're doing the same thing with all the values, then use bracket notation and iterate over the `requiredKeys`, eg - `for (const key of requiredKeys) { doSomething(obj[key]); }` If you're not doing the same thing with all the values, and you want separate identifiers, then destructure after the verification is complete. Yes, it requires a bit of duplication, but not very much (and if you want separate identifiers, there's no way around it)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If there is no way around then to me it makes sense to just hardcode `const requiredKeys = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];` and keep the code simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
const findMissingKeys = (obj, keys) => {
  const missingKeys = []
  keys.forEach(key => {
    if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key) || obj[key] === undefined || obj[key] === null) {
      missingKeys.push(key)
    }
  });  
  return missingKeys;
}
```

You can do something similar to this.

Edit 1:
Just saw that you need values to be passed as well. Changing the code accordingly

Comment: The question is how does one get the 2nd argument to your function. What problem are you trying to solve?